# Using count, groupBy, as in Slick

Tags: slick

How can I convert this sql statement to Slick in most precise, optimal way.

```
select t.*, count(v.userId) as vote from Talk t inner join Vote v on t.id = v.talkId group by t.id
```

v.**talkId** column is a **Foreign Key** to **id** column of Talk

Talk Model:

- **id**
- description
- speaker_id
- pledged_date
- create_date_time
- locked_date
- is_approved

Vote Model:

- user_id
- **talk_id**

I tried this however it throws exception *SlickException: Cannot select Path s2 in Ref s3*

```
val x = for {
      t <- models.slick.Talks
      v <- models.slick.Votes if t.id === v.talkId
    } yield (t, Query(models.slick.Votes).filter(_.talkId === t.id).length)

val y = x.groupBy(_._1.id)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
val x = (for {
  t <- models.slick.Talks
  v <- models.slick.Votes if t.id === v.talkId
} yield (t, v)).groupBy(_._1).map{ case (t,tvs) => (t,tvs.map(_._2).length) }
```